# cProgramming: misunderstanding referencing a pointer to an element of a struct of int and nested struct (also of ints)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is a sample querstion of the CLA exam of the cppinstitute

The question is what is the output of following code? the right answer is "8" and I get exactly that result, but I don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//struct of two ints
struct S1 {
    int p1,p2;
    };

// struct of an int, struct of two ints, and another int
struct S2 {
    int p1;
    struct S1 s1;
    int p2;
    };

int main(void) {
  // set an int to 0
    int s = 0;
  // invoke a struct type 2 and fill with 1, 2, 3, 4
  // like: 
  // struct S2 {
  // int p1; // = 1
  // struct S1 s1; // = 2,3
  // int p2; // = 4
  // };
    struct S2 s2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  // prepare a pointer of same type like the struct above
    struct S2 *p;
  // claim memory for the pointer
    p = (struct S2 *)malloc(sizeof(struct S2));
  // point to already filled struct
    *p = s2;
  // the int 1 is replaced with 0
    s2.p1 = 0;
  // s is assembled
  // = 1 + 0 + 4 + 3 = 7
    s = p->p1 + s2.p1 + p->p2 + p->s1.p2; // WHY p->p1 IS 1 AND NOT 0 ???
    free(p);
    printf("%d",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Aus I understood it (and wrote in the comments to make it clear to me) p->p1 is referencing the with the pointer the first element of the struct. that should be 0 (not 1), because with using the "."-operator in the staement `s2.p1 = 0;` the value of the struct s2 at the place p1 should have changed from 1 to 0. so the pointer to that element referenced with the "->"-operator should also have changed.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: `*p = s2` doesn't point to already-filled struct (that would have been `p = &s2;`). It copies the data from `s2` to the raw memory that `p` points to. Then `s2.p1 = 0` modifies `s2.p1`, but not `p->p1`. It's little different from `int x = 1; int y = x; x = 2; // y is still 1`

Comment: You are expecting something like `p = &s2;` (instead of malloc and assignment of value), and then your theories will hold.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is not pointing at `s2` so changes to `s2` have no effect on `p`.

`p` is pointing at the memory returned by `malloc`. That memory has been filled by copying the contents of `s2` here `*p = s2`, but that does not make `p` point to `s2` (that would be `p = &s2`).

If you properly understand the difference between `*p = s2` and `p = &s2` then you will have gone a fair way to understanding pointers.

Comment: *facepalm*
you're right. I am a bloody beginner, but at least I understand your explaination and now I remember the same stuff in a learning video. Need by far more practice.Thanks for clarification.